# Delete row if the value in a variable in the row above has a specific value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements, row

I would like to delete all rows in a datafile, if the value in the column "Condition" is the value of the row before + 10. So in the example below, I would like to delete the rows 1, 3, 6 and 9. Thank you for any help!

```
> data_long
   File               Condition  
1  CBM00101.EDF       1                     
2  CBM00101.EDF       11                        
3  CBM00101.EDF       3                        
4  CBM00101.EDF       13                        
5  CBM00101.EDF       2                        
6  CBM00101.EDF       3                        
7  CBM00101.EDF       13                        
8  CBM00101.EDF       1                        
9  CBM00101.EDF       2                        
10 CBM00101.EDF       12
```

I tried to do a for loop, going row by row, but I could not find a code which related to the next column.

Comment: `data_long[with(data_long, c(diff(Condition) != 10, TRUE)),]`

Comment: @r2evans post as answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

Pleased try `filter` with the below condition

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% filter(!abs(Condition-lead(Condition))==10)
```

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  File         Condition
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 CBM00101.EDF        11
2 CBM00101.EDF        13
3 CBM00101.EDF         2
4 CBM00101.EDF        13
5 CBM00101.EDF         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```r
 data_long[with(data_long, c(diff(Condition) != 10, TRUE)),] 
#            File Condition
# 2  CBM00101.EDF        11
# 4  CBM00101.EDF        13
# 5  CBM00101.EDF         2
# 7  CBM00101.EDF        13
# 8  CBM00101.EDF         1
# 10 CBM00101.EDF        12
```

This leads directly to any of the other R dialects:

```r
library(dplyr)
data_long %>%
  filter(c(diff(Condition) != 10, TRUE))
library(data.table)
as.data.table(data_long)[c(diff(Condition) != 10, TRUE),]
```

Side note: the presence and appearance of `"File"` suggests that this may need to be a *grouped* operation, doing it distinctly for each unique file. This can easily be adapted with:

```r
### base R
data_long[with(data_long,
  ave(Condition, File, FUN = function(cond) c(diff(cond) != 10, TRUE))) > 0,]
### dplyr
data_long %>%
  group_by(File) %>%
  filter(c(diff(Condition) != 10, TRUE))
### data.table
as.data.table(data_long)[, .SD[c(diff(Condition) != 10, TRUE),], by = File]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, I tried this:

data_long %>%
filter(c(diff(Condition) != 10, TRUE))

and it worked perfectly!!!